# How to add own class into field if this field is not valid?

Tags: python, django

How to add own class into field if this field is not valid?

For example if this field is not valid I would add `class="invalid"`

forms:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField()
```

template:

```
{{ form.myfield }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited to answer more precisely.

If you want to specify a class for error or required fields:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    error_css_class = 'error' #here you can set this to 'invalid'
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/

You can also change your class for one field with:

```
myfield= forms.CharField(attrs={'class': 'myclass'})
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Comment: I know this solution but I need add class only if this field have error during validation process

Comment: [Answer is right](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.error_css_class): *"The Form class has a couple of hooks you can use to add class attributes to required rows or to rows with errors"*

Answer (score 0):

In your forms clean method you could update the `attrs` of the widgets for all fields that error to achieve something similar to what you want.

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        if 'myfield' in self._errors:
            self.fields['myfield'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'invalid'})

        # Or to add the class to the input of all erroring fields:
        for field in self.fields:
            if field in self._errors:
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'invalid'})

        return super(MyForm, self).clean()
```